Can I call a subway rider "a customer"?
"Customers" typically refers to people who purchase goods or services in a commercial setting. While subway riders pay a fare, it doesn't feel like a typical customer-seller relationship. So, would you say this?

Tokyo's subway system had the most customers in 2010.


The more usual terms are passengers and commuters.
Edit
Passengers is wider than commuters and is hence a better choice when we include also the infrequent travellers.
Customers would be understood too. It's commonly used by UK rail companies like Transport for London and Great Western Railway.

If we're talking about the passenger volume, do you think "commuters" are not semantically wide enough? I mean considering the fact that many passengers ride a subway line just once or twice and therefore can't be considered a commuter.

Passengers is wider and is hence a better choice when we include also the infrequent travellers.

Transport for London is operator of one the world's largest transport networks, comprising underground/metro/'subway' trains, buses, above-ground trains, trams, buses, and river boats, and they call their users 'customers'. The Great Western Railway says 'As one of the largest train companies in Britain, more than 100 million customers a year join us on board.' This is typical of all UK rail companies.

Thanks, @Michael Harvey.   I have edited my answer.

It's ambiguous if customer is someone purchasing a ticket (who may not ride) rather than someone riding (who may not pay money). Some public transport systems may allow free riding for children or the elderly or other groups or be free for all (e.g. passenger ferries in New York or Amsterdam), and it's not clear that such people should be called customers.

@StuartF while I take your point that a 'customer' is generally defined as a user of a service for which payment is made, that payment may be made on behalf of the user. For example I have a pass allowing me free (to me) bus travel in England; the journeys are paid for out of taxation. I have no hestitation in considering myself a 'customer' of the bus companies providing the services, and neither do they. Many UK organisations call all their service users to be 'customers'.

I think the point may partly be that 'customers' is a more dignified idea than 'passengers' (which can seem a bit like 'two-legged cattle'). Customers have needs, rights, entitlement to respect, etc.

What about travelers? Would you ever use "travelers" for people using public transportation like buses, trains, or planes? For example, would you say "The number of travelers being transported by this railway system is increasing"?

Yes, travellers is possible.

When referring to the number of people who use a transit service, rider is probably the most common.

Tokyo's subway system had the most riders in 2010.

You're right that "customer" sounds odd because it isn't really a transactional relationship.
"Passenger" isn't incorrect, but there's a nuanced difference between the two. When talking about public transit, we use "passenger" more when talking about people as humans, and "rider" more when talking about people as statistics. "Passenger" focuses more on the person as a human.
So we typically talk about the number of riders who are satisfied with the service because that's a dry statistic, but we usually talk about the number of passengers killed in a subway crash to emphasize their humanity.

Would you ever use "travelers" for people using public transportation like buses, trains, or planes? For example, would you say "The number of travelers being transported by this railway system is increasing"?

@anIELTSlearner "Traveller" refers to someone going anywhere by any means, including private vehicle. It also is more often used for longer distances than commuting distance, so no, it wouldn't be my first choice. There are contexts where it would be acceptable, but I'm assuming you're asking these questions because you're preparing for a standardized test, and the answer for that is "no".
